# ListPicker inside PanoramaItem doesn't work on SDK v7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I use ListPicker from Silverlight Toolkit for WP August 2011 as below but it doesn't work

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="settings">
                <toolkit:ListPicker>
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="5" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="10" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="15" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="20" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="25" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="30" />
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Tried to replace by ListPicker from Silverlight Toolkit for WP February 2011 but it has same problem.

But I can use ListPicker from Silverlight Toolkit for WP February 2011 on an app which used SDK v7.0. Seems the problem causes by SDK v7.1

Found the reason! It's because ListPicker only can contain 5 or less than 5 items. If the list contains more than 5 items, using ListBox instead.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question then add it as an answer, not part of the question

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't allow me to answer my own question if it's the first post. Sound funny!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the rep issue. Hopefulyl you'll stick around, earn som emore rep and avoid such limitations in the future. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into a limit when the number of items is greater than 5 be sure you have set the `ItemCountThreshold` as this restricts the number of items you can have in a the control in the standard view. The default value for this is 5 so increasing it to 6 should address your issue.

See also:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/9412
and
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx

Comment: It only works with Silverlight Toolkit for WP February 2011. When I set ItemCountThreshold's value to a number bigger than 5, it throws exception (I'm using Silverlight Toolkit for WP August 2011)

Comment: @Agile Hobo How did you manage to set the ItemCountThreshold using the Aug 2011 SL WP7 Toolkit? I upgraded from Feb to Aug and one of the changes was that ItemCountThreshold was set to a read-only properly, so it should have thrown a compiler error

Comment: They changed a lot in the August edition, specially for the ListPicker. The "Expanded" mode been removed.

Comment: @Blakomen When I set value to ItemCountThreshold via XAML, it doesn't thrown a compiler error. It throws exception at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the ListPicker from the August 2011 version of the SLWP7 toolkit with seven items, so I don't think your hard limit of 5 is correct in general, though it might be specific to being in a panorama item. When you say it doesn't work, do you mean nothing happens when you try to use it (ie doesn't register the Tap event), or doesn't display at all?

One caveat to note is that you can't use ListPicker within a Scrollviewer - this is a known issue with the Aug 2011 version of the SL toolkit (see http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/9379) There are a few workarounds to this that i havent tried, mainly to do with changing the Tap event handler: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/90708.aspx and http://attowares.com/blog/2011/08/23/listpicker-inside-scrollviewer-wp7-toolkit-mango/ There might be something with the Panorama Item that is affecting the ListPicker in the same way...

But my main point is that you **can** use ListPicker with more than 5 items.

Comment: I've just tried to add a ListPicker with 6 items to a potrait page and have [System.ArgumentException] = {"The parameter is incorrect. "}. Same exception when I add ListPicker to a panorama item.

Comment: BTW, here is place I found that ListPicker only can contains 5 or less items http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/01/update-to-list-picker-control.aspx (see the comments below)

Comment: Can you show me the code that demonstrates how to add more than 5 items? Thanks

Comment: This isn't going to format very well, but - xaml:                     <toolkit:ListPicker FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" Header="Primary Type" Name="PrimaryActionType">
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>

Comment: and codebehind - List<string> Stats = new List<string>();
            Stats.Add("none");
            Stats.Add("STR");
            Stats.Add("VIT");
            Stats.Add("DEX");
            Stats.Add("INT");
            Stats.Add("MND");
            Stats.Add("LUK");


            PrimaryActionType.ItemsSource = Stats;

Comment: and the FullModeItemTemplate, placed in Application.Resources -         <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}" Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: @AgileHobo also regarding your link, it looks like it's talking about the WP7 Design Templates which are UI guidelines (and not necessarily actually related to the functional specifics of the ListPicker control in the SLToolkit).

Comment: IMO, it must be ListPicker's error. While it allows to bind ItemSource with more than 5 items but it doesn't to add more than 5 items in XAML.